# Mapping Many-to-One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I want to register warehouses that are part of an organization.
I also want for the warehouses to have an attribute identifying the organization as a foreign key. However, I don't want to persist anything on the organization table (This one is already with all the data it needs) when I register a warehouse, I only want to persist the organizationId on the warehouse table and then get the information about the organization when I fetch a warehouse. I am trying to this with Quarkus Hibernate ORM.

This is my model class:

```
@Entity
public class Warehouse {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "warehouse_sequence", sequenceName = "warehouse_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "warehouse_sequence")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Organization organizationId;
    private String name;

... getters and setters ...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

... getters and setters ...
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work for your exact model. Moreover, unidirectional case (like in your model) is more usable from my experience.
This is more elaborated example - https://allaroundjava.com/many-to-one-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The thing is that when I try to persist the warehouse, I get the following message `Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Warehouse`.

Comment: This is most likely due to incorrect transaction handling, can you please show the code for persisting the entities?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` causing the problem (Foreign key column has the same name as the primary key)?
Can you try renaming it like:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
private Organization organizationId;
```